# Cannot find symbol @Mapper annotation for Mapstruct

Tags: java, annotations, mapstruct

Im trying to use Mapstruct in my application. I included the dependency and see that it has been successfully downloaded into my project, but the @Mapper annotation is not being recognized.

[image]

My relevant dependencies are as follows

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.30</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

When this alone didn't work, I added it to the annotation processorPaths in maven-compiler-plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>17</source>
                <target>17</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.30</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.5.Final</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Some sources said order of the paths might matter, swapping them around didn't help. I also tried added the following path to annotationProcessorPaths:

```
<path>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.0</version>
</path>
```

This also did not work. I also tried adding mapstruct-processor as a dependency directly and that didn't help either.

I am using Intellij and "Enable annotation processing" is checked. Any ideas whats happening here?

Using Java 17 by the way.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but do you have `import org.mapstruct.Mapper` in your `GameStateMapper`?